# Failed to Generate Authentication Token for vimeo(vimeo integration into rails application)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, vimeo

I have been trying to Generate Authentication Token for vimeo through rails application

```
response = RestClient.post "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize",
                           :response_type => "code",
                           :client_id => '2c8f2be58dcce1f61bc4f0a86dfb8d1bc214a7e0',

                           :redirect_uri => 'http://staging.tutorsweb.com',
                           :state => 'as684fad2asdflkjsadf4521s'
```

The above code is how i'm sending request to vimeo.

The response is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Authentication error on Vimeo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://f.vimeocdn.com/styles/css_opt/auth.min.css?508754847a">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" media="(resolution: 326dpi)" href="https://f.vimeocdn.com/images_v6/apple-touch-icon-114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" media="(resolution: 163dpi)" href="https://f.vimeocdn.com/images_v6/apple-touch-icon-57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" media="(resolution: 132dpi)" href="https://f.vimeocdn.com/images_v6/apple-touch-icon-72.png">
</head>
<body>
<div id="authorization">
    <header class="page">
                <div id="logo">
            <a href="//vimeo.com" title="Go home">
                <img class="svg" src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/logo.svg" alt="Go home" width="140" height="40">
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="content">
        <div id="security" style="display:none">
            <script>if(self==top){document.getElementById("security").style.display="block"}else{top.location=self.location}</script>
            <h3 class="hot">Uh oh, something went wrong!</h3>

<p>An error has occurred. You won't be able to connect to Vimeo until it is fixed by the developer.</p>

    <p>Hm. We're not sure what you're trying to do. Please contact the service you want to connect to Vimeo, and tell them,</p>

    <p>"We were unable to provide your user an oauth2 authorization code because the redirect URI or client ID were missing."</p>

<p><a class="btn btn_gray" onclick="window.history.back();return false">Go back</a></p>
        </div>
        <noscript>
            <h3 class="hot">JavaScript Required</h3>
            <p>In order to protect your Vimeo account from unauthorized access, this page requires JavaScript.</p>
        </noscript>
    </section>

    <footer>
        You can change any application access preferences from your <a href="//vimeo.com/settings/extend">settings page</a>.            </footer>
</div>
<script>var token=document.getElementById('token');if(token){document.cookie='xsrft=' + token.value}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have been following https://github.com/matthooks/vimeo/tree/master I tried matthooks also but it didnt worked for me.

Please suggest me what to do?
and how i can Generate Authentication Token of vimeo for my rails application with example

Answer (score 0):

This first step is intended for your clients. You should build this link and send them to via a browser.

If you only need an access token for yourself, you can generate it on your app page in the [developer site](http://developer.vimeo.com/apps)

You can also read more in [Vimeo's authentication documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

The vimeo gem by matthooks still using the old Simple and Advanced APIs of Vimeo. Those are no longer supported, though the endpoints are still around and function; Vimeo has been pushing users to Version 3.x.

For what you are trying to do, you might find that the [API Specification](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec)
might be helpful. That will allow you to tie your calls to a specific version of the API. Couple that with the [API Authentication Specification](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) and you should have the info you need to craft your request.

Using curl as a testing platform, the non-user authentication can be as simple as:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <OAUTH_TOKEN>" https://api.vimeo.com
```

Good luck!